# Linux sed command that generates a new file on every regex match

Tags: bash

I have the following Linux command which I am using to extract data from one very large log file.

```
sed -n "/<trade>/,/<\/trade>/p" Large.log > output.xml
```

However, the output is generated in a single file **output.xml**. My intention is to create a new file every time the `"/<trade>/,/<\/trade>/p"` is matched. Every new file will be named after the **`<id>`** tag which is inside the **`<trade>`** **`</trade>`** tags.

Something likes this...

```
sed -n "/<trade>/,/<\/trade>/p" Large.log > "/<id>/,/<\/id>/p".xml
```

However, that, of course, does not work and I am not sure how to apply a regex as a naming rule.

P.S At this point, I am also not sure if I should use **`sed`** or maybe I should try achieving this with **`awk`**

Comment: [Don't Parse XML/HTML With Regex.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/3776858) I suggest to use an XML/HTML parser (xmlstarlet, xmllint ...).

Comment: Thanks, for the suggestion @Cyrus, but I am not allowed to use third party libraries for this one.

Comment: Suggestion 2: Take a look at XSLT/XPATH for using that also with XML/HTML parser  - Or let the Endpoint do that instead server side. But OK - While i was wroting you place your 'not allowed' comment - @Cyrus Thanx alot for the link - LOL - Now i know where the pandemic desease come from ;-)

Comment: since output filename is determined by the contents of the file, I'd opt for a `awk` solution, making sure to `close()` a file once you're done writing to it (due to some `awk` implementations not being able to maintain many open file descriptors); how easy/hard this may be (parsing with `awk`) will depend on the formatting of the file; if you have problems with a `awk` solution I'd suggest starting a new question and make sure to provide a) sample input, the `awk` code you've written, c) the wrong output generated by your code, and d) the desired output